# Same CSS Slector Not Working in Internet Explorer but works in firefox

Tags: java, selenium

I created a custom css selector in this example for an element(Link) (for gmail page). It works fine in Firefox but it throws up an error in internet explorer(version 9.0); IE is launched but throws below error and I also tried with other locator but same error.

Error in Internet Explorer

---

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == a[id='gmail-sign-in'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 307 milliseconds

Code for Firefox - Work Fine

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail_FFX {
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //Creating Driver and Launching the site
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://gmail.com");
      System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


     WebElement objLink;
     objLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id='gmail-sign-in']"));
             objLink.click(); 
   }
}
```

Code in Internet Explorer - throws error

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
```

public class IE_Gmail {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //Creating Driver and Launching the site
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:/Selenium/IE Driver/IEDriverServer.exe"); 
      WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://gmail.com");
      System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


      WebElement objLink;
      objLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id='gmail-sign-in']"));
      objLink.click();
 }  

}
```

Comment: Help me convince everyone to switch to Firefox/Webkit. Problem solved. Or just ignore IE support until they're forced to switch.

Comment: Can't you just find element by id?

Comment: @Evgeniy - i also tried that but same error.

Comment: @keyser - are you referring to rendering engine of browser, i couldn't understand your comment.

Comment: @user1925406 - did you try to debug your code with IE9?

Comment: Better you can use xpath in these case

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
With the available DOM Structure get the perfect Object Locator as per ur code Already Object ID is available for Sign In Link.

Object ID of Gmail Sign In Link:gmail-sign-in

Operation to Perform:click -- How

driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();

The Locator Object ID is faster and accessible in all browsers.